# ReactCSSTransitionGroup animate table cells

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I would like to update values in table cells `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` and animate visually when the value is changed in real-time, but having problems: Table rows don't seem to update, while multiple divs have display discrepency:

http://jsfiddle.net/jj0byzz0/33/

Here is the example :

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var AniTest = React.createClass({
render: function () {
    var content = this.state.numbers.map(function(number){
        return (
           <tr key={number}>      
           <td>
           <ReactCSSTransitionGroup component="div" transitionName="aninumber"  >            
               <div key={number}>{number}</div>
           </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
           </td>
           </tr>
        )
    });

    return (
          <div>  
             <ReactCSSTransitionGroup  transitionName="aninumber"  >            
                <div key={this.state.numbers[0]}> {this.state.numbers[0]} </div>
                <div key={this.state.numbers[1]}> {this.state.numbers[1]} </div>
              </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
              <br/>
              Table Animation

              <table >
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      {content}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
    )
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    setInterval(this.updateNumbers, 5000); 

},

updateNumbers: function() {

    this.setState({numbers:[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)]});

},

getInitialState: function(props){
    return {
        numbers:[1,2]
    };

}
});

React.render(<AniTest/>, document.getElementById("anitest"));
```

and the css :

```
.aninumber-enter {
  background-color: green;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

.aninumber-enter.aninumber-enter-active {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.aninumber-leave {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

.aninumber-leave.aninumber-leave-active {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't insert multiple CSSTransitionGroup tags inside your content variable. Instead, remove the explicit tbody tag, and replace with:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup component="tbody" transitionName="aninumber">
{content}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

This single TransitionGroup renders as a tbody element and controls the animation of the tr children inside.

working fiddle using React v0.13: http://jsfiddle.net/faria/tefxbjtL/

Comment: Thank you Faria - the animation is still not quite working - when updating a value, it flickers by inserting the new number and only then hiding the old value. Also - I actually do need to animate separately the calls of a table (in different colors depending on the values)

Comment: You can specify whether to disable the enter, or exit transition effect so that only one occurs, this will solve your flicker problem.  With regards to the other issue of animating table cells individually, your TransitionGroup was a child of a tr element which was also keyed. In this case, I think the tr row was being removed before the TransitionGroup even had a chance to activate. The React docs only show examples of the TransitionGroup as a parent managing its children, so that might be another question to post.